# How to update a form view with JavaScript in Odoo10

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo-10

Thanks for your help in first.

For a project, I need to create a dynamic table with JavaScript on a FormView but I'm stuck ... I don't know how I can access to the view and update the table, files are correctly read by Odoo (Js, CSS). I tried a lot of things like use console.log for look in the object but nothing seem good to me :( .

For now i have this code :

```
odoo.define('ms_contract.view_form_intervention', function (require){
    "use strict";
    var form_widget = require('web.form_widgets');
    var core = require('web.core');
    var _t = core._t;
    var QWeb = core.qweb;
    var Widget = require('web.Widget');
    var View = require('web.View');
    console.log(Widget);
    console.log(form_widget);
    console.log(core);
    console.log(_t);
    console.log(QWeb);
    console.log(View);
});
```

Comment: Refer this: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/javascript.html

This might be helpful to you..

Answer (score 0):

You can define odoo `widget` to call any javascript code. Explore more about it. If you try to be more specific about your need then. May be I can help in a better way.